# Script to check if file exists and copy

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Pretty new to shell script,
want to write script which checks if any file `.300` extension exists on `/exports/files` on  server 10.xx.xx.xx.  If `*.300` exists, move file to `/exports/files/arch` and send an email to `support@abc.com`.  If `*.300` isn't found then do nothing.

I tried below suggestion:

```
#! /bin/bash

    for FILE in `ls /exports/files/*.300`
    do
       mv $FILE /exports/files/arch
       echo "$FILE moved" | mailx -s $FILE moved support@abc.com 
    done
```

When there is no files its erroring out saying `ls: cannot access /exports/files/*.300: No such file or directory`.  Is there any way to suppress this...

Comment: This really sounds an awful lot like a homework problem...

Comment: @john all things are difficult before they are easy, a i said i am new to scripting,I am still learning.Thanks for your comment though

Comment: I didn't say anything about difficulty. I said it sounds like it was assigned as a homework problem.

Comment: Tell me if you mount the 10.*** server export on your pc

Comment: @elbarna so far i got this and still working on it.I am running this on 10.xx.xx.xx server   #!/bin/bash
if ls /home/export/files/.300* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
mv .300* /home/export/files/archive
echo ".300 extenstion found and moved" | mailx  -s "file found and moved" support@abc.com
fi            nothing happens

Comment: @Zairabanu did you want to send multiple files ? If 1.500 and a.500 exist, which condition(alphabetical's first file, ctime...etc) you want to choose to decide which file to move ?

Comment: @林果皞 yes . any file .300 extension should be moved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob #to make `("$src_dir"*.300)` works
src_dir="/exports/files/" #don't forget trailing slash /
dest_dir="/exports/files/arch/" #don't forget trailing slash /
err_f="/tmp/error.txt"
mv_f="/tmp/moved.log" #record moved file in case network down
email="support@abc.com"
touch "$err_f" #bcoz we use >> apppend
touch "$mv_f" #bcoz we use tee -a append
if [ ! -d "$src_dir" ]; then echo|mailx -s "Error: directory $src_dir not exist" "$email" 2>>"$err_f"; exit 1; fi
if [ ! -d "$dest_dir" ]; then echo|mailx -s "Error: directory $dest_dir not exist" "$email" 2>>"$err_f"; exit 1; fi
{
f=("$src_dir"*.300)
for ((i=0; i < ${#f[@]}; i+=1)); do
        mv -f "${f[i]}" "$dest_dir"  2>>"$err_f"; #-f do not prompt
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                if [ "$i" -eq 0 ]; then echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"; echo "The following files has been moved from $src_dir to $dest_dir"; echo; fi
                echo "$((i+1))." "$(basename "${f[i]}")" 'moved'; echo;
        else
                 echo| mailx -s "Error:  $(<"$err_f")" "$email" 2>>"$err_f"; break
        fi
done
} | tee -a "$mv_f" | mailx -E -s "The following files has been moved" "$email" 2>>"$err_f"
```

Example mail inbox screeshoot:

Received mail when `mv` error:
[image]

Received mail when `mv` success:
[image]

**/tmp/moved.log** to log files moved and **/tmp/error.txt** to log all erros, both files used to keep log even **network down**:
[image]

**Note:**

1. You shouldn't parse the output of`ls`
2. mailx -E to avoid empty body, so it wouldn't sent if no file moved
3. mailx only one if `mv` encounter error, by using `break` to break early instead of `exit 1` because we still want to know which file has been moved before error occur.
4. Advantage of `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]` compare to implicitly `if cmd` is you can easily modify it to some other command which might require different return code.
5. You should manually remove both /tmp/error.txt and /tmp/moved.log which will append from time to time.

**Reference:**

1. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
2. http://lcorg.blogspot.com/2009/04/tip-redirecting-multiple-command.html
3. https://serverfault.com/questions/349989/sending-mail-from-command-line-if-body-not-empty
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036763/get-formatted-date-from-timestamp-with-rounded-milliseconds-bash-shell-script

Comment: works well but it sends individual email of each file.Is there a way i can send all file names in one mail?

Comment: @Zairabanu Actually i have no idea what's your real requirement. 1. What if arch directory does not exist ? Then all the *.500 will rename to arch single file. 2. "is it possible to send 1 email with all file in it? " You can compress your directory and then attach to you email.

Comment: both directory exist ,if .300 extension file exist in /exports/files then it should be moved to /exports/files/arch.If .300 file doesnot exist then it shouldnot do anything. all files moved i want in single email .

Comment: both the directory exists , if .300 extension file exist in /exports/files then it should be moved to /exports/files/arch.If .300 file doesnot exist then it shouldnot do anything. And if the file exists and is moved, then should receive email with details(name of the file) of file ?

Comment: @Zairabanu How about redirect/append the output to a single file and then attach it to the mailx ? You don't want to concat "y.500 moved x.500 moved" as your email title(based on your `-s $FILE` ), right ?

Comment: email title is mailx -s "The following files has been moved" support@abc.com. donot want all file names in email title :)

Comment: As  I see your email screenshot...is it possible to add like... date  then next line the following files has been moved from /export/files to export/files/arch then next line the list of files

Comment: one interesting question is--not sure if this is possible--is it possible to set from address to like some dummy address-- like filecopyscript-no-reply@abc.com .in that way who every gets the email will know that you cannot reply to it....above screen shot shows your email address--cant we hide it by mentioning a dummy address--

Comment: added   -r from-filecopyscript-no-reply@abc.com   that worked  thanks again---if u have some other trick let me know..thanks

Comment: @Zairabanu You can do `export replyto="<limkokhole+noreply@gmail.com>"` on top (e.g.email="support@abc.com" here) to make it go to this mail when click reply button. Also mailx -S argument, i.e `-S "from=stackoverflow.com noreply <noreply>"` if you are using gmail as your email domain and you want to notify user noreply on top behind the email.

Comment: confused, can you pls update that in above script-- i  did following mailx -E -r From-script-no-reply@abc.com -s "The following files has been moved" "$email"    this worked

Comment: @Zairabanu the new -S i suggested is uppercase S, try to add it inside the mailx you may see the difference. For example(don't put -r here):
`mailx -E  -S "from=mycompany.com noreply <noreply>" -s "The following files has been moved" "$email"`

Comment: @Zairabanu and export replyto will useful when user click reply button, it will fill with specific replyto email address, i.e:
`omission...
err_f="/tmp/error.txt";
email="support@abc.com";
export replyto="<noreply@abc.com>";
if [ ! -d "$src_dir" ]; then... omission

Comment: @Zairabanu i'm not going to update the script again because this is too far from the original topic :)

Comment: that worked, no need to update,,this looks better...thanks 林果皞

Comment: appreciate your time and thank you for your help.may success follow you :) good luck :)

Comment: Cool. /tmp/error.txt will log errors? I didn't see any errors in the file when my failed?

Comment: @Zairabanu it will log only when `mv` failed, e.g. mv: cannot move ‘./t1/y.300’ to ‘./t1/kk/y.300’: Permission denied

Comment: Made me to fail by removing the destination directory...it sent me error in email saying that destination directory does not exist.. error.txt is empty

Comment: Made me - made mv

Comment: @Zairabanu Of course, i didn't put   2>"$err_f" when directory not exist. You should able to understand my code, right?

Comment: Oh yeah! Right. I missed that part.

Comment: /tmp/error.txt didnot log error if directory donot exist.i removed destination directory,it sent me an email saying directory donot exist.But error.txt is empty/Have tried removing destination directory and running the script

Comment: @Zairabanu it's expected behaviour.  `echo|mailx -s "Error: directory $src_dir not exist" "$email" 2>>"$err_f"` means send "directory not exist" error to mailbox, stderr `2>>` is empty of course. But if network down/failure, then stderr 2>>"$err_f" will log down network error, such as "Cannot open gmail smtp:587". If you want to log "directory not found" even network is up(mailx success), then you can use tee to do it.

Comment: the script runs fine on linux box but when i tried to run this on AIX Box , i see this error in error.txt  -->mailx: Not a recognized flag: E... any idea

Comment: I THINK i cannot use -E flad :( http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mail.htm

Comment: @Zairabanu You can try to get `ifne` utility(by install `moreutils` package), manpages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/ifne.1.html, then you can do something like `...| tee -a "$mv_f" | ifne mailx -s...` If you can't find a way to install it, then get the source from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/madx/moreutils/master/ifne.c , `gcc ifne.c -o ifne` to compile it, then copy into `/usr/bin/`(or whenever relevant env path), and use this command as described above.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this should do the trick. If you need to remote in to the server use ssh certificates and executes this script using ssh.

```
    #! /bin/bash

    for FILE in `ls /exports/files/*.300`
    do
       mv $FILE /exports/files/arch
       echo "$FILE moved" | mailx -s $FILE moved support@abc.com 
    done
```

Comment: if there are multiple files with .300 extension , will this send multiple emails...and also its returning error if the file is not found , is there any way to suppress the error

Comment: if there are multiple files with .300 extension , will this send multiple emails..?.and also its returning error if the file is not found and alos sends email even though the file is not found or moved , is there any way to suppress the error

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
 #! /bin/bash

ls /exports/files/*.300 | while read FILE 
do
   if mv $FILE /exports/files/arch
   then echo "$FILE moved" 
fi
done | mailx -s files moved support@abc.com
```

will give you a single mail with all moved file, and skipping the error.

with just 3 level of pipes.

## Edit:

with few files :

```
#! /bin/bash
if ls /exports/files/*.300 > /dev/null 2>&1
then 

   ls /exports/files/*.300 | awk '{printf "%s moved\n",$0 }' | mailx -s files moved support@abc.com
   mv /exports/files/*.300 /exports/files/arch

 else 
   echo no .300 file found | mailx -s no .300 files moved support@abc.com

fi
```

in case of arg list too long

```
#! /bin/bash
if ls /exports/files/*.300 > /dev/null 2>&1
then 
   ls /exports/files/*.300 | while read FILE 
   do
      if mv $FILE /exports/files/arch
      then echo "$FILE moved" 
      fi
   done | mailx -s files moved support@abc.com 
fi
```

Comment: when i run this script "ls"errors out ...No such file or directory
Null message body; hope that's ok   --->thats the message i get

Comment: @Zairabanu: His script should work. You'll need to do some debugging to figure out why it breaks. Try removing the `| mailx...` command and see what your output looks like. There is no way to go into the `then` clause unless `ls` finds something in the beginning. You can also do this after the `then`: (all on one line) `ls /exports/files/*.300; exit` and see what it prints. Your error is very odd.

Comment: @MikeS on the top most script, in case of no foo.300 files, ls loop is empty, thus generating a mail with no body.

Comment: @Archemar above script worked,i removed word " moved" from echo line as its keep on repating like file1 moved, file2 moved.Is there a way we can add a date before(above) "$FILE moved"

Comment: @Archemar above script worked,i removed word " moved" from echo line as its keep on repating like file1 moved, file2 moved.Is there a way we can add a date before(above) "$FILE moved"